Question about Spike PK Post-Simulation Information
I am confused about the meaning of 'ticks' in the post-sim output of Spike PK simulation.
I am running some C programs with Spike simulator. I use the following command to run the simulation:
spike pk -s myprogram
The program runs fine and the simulator outputs some information after the program execution.
Example:

950 ticks
41203 cycles
41203 instructions
1.00 CPI

Does 'ticks' here mean the cycles per second? Hope to see some clarification on this.
